# What is a .c.h file?

Tags: c, file, header-files

When looking through the CPython source code I came across a file called [listobject.c.h](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/clinic/listobject.c.h). I'm not sure what this file extension ".c.h" is. The file has a mix of function prototypes and function definitions. Is there a reason to add .c to the extension instead of just making it a .h file?

I couldn't find any information about this file extension on Google since they remove special characters in search queries so I got information about .ch files instead.

Comment: You could look through the rest of the source and build files to see if it's used somewhere, and how it's used.

Comment: It appears to be a custom thing in the project. You'll have read the project or its documentation to figure it out.

Comment: Anyone can use any file 'extension' for any reason they care to invent.   But my guess would be that it's autogenerated code -- see the comment `[clinic start generated code]`.  And the output file name is created by just adding '.h' to the source name, because that's easy to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has no generally applicable meaning, but typically, it's used to imply that it's *really* an implementation file that, due to the needs of the build system, is `#include`-ed in another file.

Normal header files provide prototypes and declarations, and typically only provide implementations of things that are declared `inline` or `static` (and even `static` is frowned on unless link-time optimization is used to deduplicate the compiled versions of it). Providing other sorts of implementations risks repeated definitions of the same visible entities in multiple compiled object files, leading to problems with duplicates at link time. Since the `.c.h` file in this case is intended to be `#include`ed in *exactly* one file (e.g. `longobject.c.h` is only intended to be included in `longobject.c` in the parent directory), there are no problems with `#include`ing it, as it won't create duplicate definitions.

The reason CPython specifically uses them is [the Argument Clinic](https://devguide.python.org/development-tools/clinic/). It's a tool that lets them generate optimized argument parsing code for built-ins without having to either:

1. Hand-write optimal parsing code on a function-by-function basis, or
2. Rely on general purpose, "`printf`-like" parsing APIs that are convenient, but less efficient

As an extra benefit, when they improve their parsing framework and options (e.g. when they added vectorcall as an option for implementing methods/functions), Argument Clinic can be updated in one place, and the benefits immediately accrue across the entire code base.

Because Argument Clinic regenerates the files from scratch on each run, they can't be easily incorporated into the hand-written "real work" implementation functions without creating a lot of code churn and causing problems for people submitting patches, so they factored out the generated code into the `.c.h` files to avoid conflicts like that.